# linear transformation with transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $C=(w_1, w_2)$ and $B=(v_1, v_2)$  be basis of $R^2$.

$u \in R^2$.

and: $[T]_C^B=$  $$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & -2 \\
    -3 & 5  \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

$T(T(u))=w_1+2w_2$

$v_1=(1 \space 5)^T$
$v_2=(-3 \space 1)^T$

What is $T(u)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** The inverse of the given matrix is $[T^{-1}]^C_B$, and multiply it by $(1,2)^T$ to get the coordinates of $T(u)$ in basis $B$.